Images wont load from array into Slideshow in react js
Hello there friendly People from Stack overflow,
I'm working on a little Homepageproject and trying to build an Imagecarrusell. So I thought it would be a good Idea making a .js file only for an const that holds an array of images. But the Images wont load. Here is my attempt(the galleryslider is not finished but the pictures don't load):
I tried to change the way I load the Pictures, either from public or by changing format to json, or using import at the top, but that beats the reason for the array or json.
In the end I want to use the SliderData.js file also to fill a gallery, so if pictures get exchanged they get exchanged on both the gallery and the slider matching. But with no loading pictures.
SliderData.js:
export const SliderData =[
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild1.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'src/components/Assests/Bild2.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'src/components/Assests/Bild3.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild4.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild5.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild6.jpg', title: 'img1'},
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild7.jpg', title: 'img1'}
{src:'public/images/gallery/Bild6.jpg', title: 'img1'},
]

GallerySilder.js:
import React from 'react'
import { SliderData } from './SliderData'


const GallerySlider = () => {
  return (
    <>
      {SliderData.map((slide, index) => {
        return(
      <img src={slide.image} alt='Graffiti'/>
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}

export default GallerySlider  


Typo.  The code is looking for a property called image on the array elements, and there is no such property.  There are src and title properties.

you are giving the wrong src,
try doing this:
  <img src={slide.src} alt='Graffiti'/>


I solved my Issue by loading the pictures into the array like this:
{img: require('./Assests/Der Akos.jpg'), title: 'img1'},

Atm I am trying to put the slider and the gallery together or rather said I am putting in a onClick function to set the slider to show or not, but man I am still so bad at react XD
And thank you for your help. I will also test that :)
